# How do we translate the Greek word ἐλογίσθη (elogisthē)?

Tags: greek, romans

Rom 4:3 BLB

> For what does the Scripture say? “And Abraham believed God, and it was reckoned to him for righteousness.”

Rom 4:3 YLT

> for what doth the writing say? 'And Abraham did believe God, and it was reckoned to him--to righteousness;'

How do we translate the word ἐλογίσθη (elogisthē)?

Comment: have you checked the dictionary meaning from biblehub?

Comment: The OP has clearly done their homework and checked the Greek underlying the English translation. The breadth of scope of the word ἐλογίσθη requires some study, hence the question being asked.

Comment: Hi Faith, as Michael is saying it would be helpful to show what you have found so far from your own investigation on this question.

Answer (score 5):

> επιστευσεν δε αβρααμ τω θεω και **ελογισθη** αυτω εις δικαιοσυνην

> [Romans 4:3 -  TR (undisputed) - Beza, Stephanus, Elzevir and Scrivener are all identical]

[*Logizomai* Strong 3049](https://biblehub.com/greek/3049.htm) is a deponent verb, thus it is middle voice or responsive. It is a response to an action. Some call this 'reflexive'.

The word appears in the NT several times and also in the Septuagint in regard to Abraham. The words 'Abraham believed God and it was 'accounted'/'reckoned' to him unto righteousness' appear several times in exactly the same form.

*Logizomai* is God's *response* to Abraham's *faith.*

*Logizomai* is a matter of evaluation. This can be seen in Paul's use of the word in regard to 'treasuring up' weekly contributions so that there should be no gatherings of large numbers of small denomination coins when he arrives. They should add to their savings, then 'treasure up' to a small number of high denomination coins, easily transported on Paul's further journey, 1 Corinthians 16:2.

*Concentration of value* is the concept lying behind the word.

A value is concentrated, and an estimation of that value is made.

'Accounting' is useful but has too much association with finance and coinage. 'Logicate' would be useful and it is available in the English language but has not been used, 'reckoning' having developed but 'reckoning' has bad connotations, a 'reckoning' behind the 'reckoning' ; a hint of deviousness in the reckoning.

*Logizomai*, in the way in which it is used, *particularly by Paul*, is a matter of the *logical assessment* of ***real value.***

---

God sees the faith of Abraham.

In that faith he sees his own righteousness, for that is what Abraham saw. Abram, as he then was, saw that God had promised and that God was true and that God would do what he had promised . . . . **because God is righteous**.

And Abram believed God.

And God saw that faith and saw the **content** of the faith.

And 'there was' (there is no subject) 'evaluated' (*logizomai*) 'to' (an indirect object) 'him' . . .  'unto' (another indirect object, a prepositional clause) 'righteousness'.

> ... there was evaluated to him unto righteousness

Abraham had, and has, no righteousness of his own. There is evaluated to him, *unto* (it is always *eis*) the righteousness of God (at the time not stated, because there was no full revelation, then, of the source of the righteousness ; for it was yet to be revealed in Paul's gospel).

That is to say, by faith, he is justified with the righteousness of God, for it is the righteousness of God that he believes and that is what is in his faith.

God sees it in his faith.
And attributes it to him.

It would be wrong *not* to attribute it to him.

Comment: Great explanation.  Can you make your translation clearer in your answer as to how that verse should be translated.  And should be use this understanding consistently?

Comment: I have heard it said that the potential that God see in each of us is His own potential (Eph. 4:2-7).  Excellent answer! +1

Answer (score 2):

Reading [Barnes’ commentary](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/romans/4-3.htm) on Rom 4:3, I was struck by his observation regarding the word ἐλογίσθη:

> I have examined all the passages, and as the result of my examination
> have come to the conclusion, that there is not one in which the word
> is used in the sense of reckoning or imputing to a man what does not
> strictly belong to him; or of charging on him what ought not to be
> charged on him as a matter of personal right.

Though I agree with Barnes that ἐλογίσθη refers to the act of believing, I cannot see why it is necessary to credit to man something that already belongs to him. If faith belongs “strictly” to man, if it is his as a matter of personal right, then why the need to state that it is reckoned or credited to him? That faith was imputed to Abraham suggests that man, in fact, cannot claim full rights of ownership. In other words, faith is not man’s by right but by imputation. Faith, after all, is a response to God’s call (Jn 6:44 & 65, Rom 10:17). It is God who initiates and God who guides the way, but faith is credited to man out of God’s abundant grace and goodness.

Given these considerations, I prefer the NKJ’s rendering, which has Abraham’s faith as “accounted to” him and “for” righteousness.

> For what does the Scripture say? “Abraham believed God, and it was
> accounted to him for righteousness.”

Comment: Very insightful. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here are the senses of λογίζομαι in the New Testament.

**Figure 1.** Senses of λογίζομαι in the New Testament (generated with Logos Bible Software)
[image]

However, remember Paul was quoting the Old Testament (Gen. 15:6). Thus, λογίζομαι translates the Hebrew word חשׁב.  We can narrow down the meaning by the overlap between the two words.

**Figure 2.** Senses of חשׁב in the Old Testament.
[image]

Thus, *to consider (reckon)* is the overlap.  However, this does have a positive sense like *credit*.  It is not the Hebrew word שׁקל which means *to weigh* or *to consider* in the sense of still evaluating; that is, the evaluation was finished.

Comment: The evaluation was finished ... and then He called Abram!  +1

Answer (score 1):

The lexical form of the operative verb in Rom 4:3 is λογίζομαι (logizomai), which, according to BDAG means:

> 1. to determine by mathematical process, reckon, calculate, eg, 1 Cor 13:5, 2 Cor 5:19, Rom 4:3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 22, etc
> 2. to give careful thought to a matter, think (about), consider, ponder, let one's mind dwell upon, eg, John 11:50, Heb 11:19, 2 Cor
>    10:11, 7, 2a, etc
> 3. to hold a view about something, think, believe, be of the opinion, eg, Rom 8:8, 2:3, 14:14, etc.

Obviously BDAG allocates the first meaning as #1 above in Rom 4:3.

This is part of Paul's larger point where he uses an accounting term as a metaphor for justification.  “Credit”, “account”, “imputed”, or “reckoned” (Greek: logizomai) is a financial or accounting term used in the market place but was employed by Paul to denote the act of God in crediting Abraham (and sinners generally) as righteous when they trusted in God, apart from the works of the law, as a free gift.  The idea is based upon the assumption that sin creates a debt to God which must be repaid (Col 2:13-15, Matt 6:12).

Again, it is only an analogue, metaphor or figure of speech and so is not literally true.  (Rom 4:3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 22, 23, 24, 2 Cor 5:19, Gal 3:6, James 2:23.  See also Gen 15:6.)  That is, the righteousness of God is “imputed” to the undeserving sinner, freely.  Thus, God “cancels the debt” (Matt 18:21-35).

Comment: Not so. Justification is not based on a notion, or a grammatical expression, that is not 'literally true'. Justification is firmly based on the righteousness of God, and His view of faith and what faith contains.

Comment: @NigelJ - I fully agree - the idea of commercial credit is the metaphor - paying a "debt" is the metaphor - to whom does God pay the debt and to whom is it owed - that is what is not literally true.  Otherwise, we have God paying a debt to (say) Satan or someone for our sins.

Comment: It is the Mediator who takes the debt upon himself, Christ Jesus, and suffers the wrath and indignation of the Deity, bearing sins in his own body on the tree. Faith sees this demonstration of the righteousness of God (sparing not his Son) and believes. And to such who have _this kind of faith_ God sees within that faith His Own Righteousness . . . .  and attributes it to them.

Comment: @NigelJ - that is all true and couched in very metaphorical language.  To whom is the debt paid and what is paid?  Or, in the language of Rom 3, is a legal acquittal?  Or is it a free gift?  Or is it a manumission?  Or is it a cloak of righteousness?  Or is it a propitiation?  Or, in the language of Matt 20:28, Rom 5:19, 2 Cor 5:21 is it a penal substitutionary execution? etc,etc,

Comment: The debt is owed to God by us and paid to God by God for us.  That is justification, acquittal, free gift, manumission, cloak, propitiation, substitution, ...  Earthly words attempting to encapsulate heavenly things. +1